# absdiff work on grayscale and not BGR colourspace

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

The difficulty I am facing is a live background subtraction. Have tried many methods but to no avail. The task I am trying to achieve is to remove a background image that the camera have snapped with a real time video that the camera is streaming.

`absdiff` is the method that I am using for my background subtraction currently as it seems to produce the best results so far.

My code is as show:

```
 while(1)
{
    capture>>imagef;
    imshow("image with foreground", imagef);
    imagef.convertTo(imagef, CV_8UC3);
    //cvtColor(imagef, imagef, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    absdiff(imagef,imageb, imageFinal); //imageb is the background image
    imshow("after diff", imageFinal);


    //cvtColor(imageFinal, imageFinal, CV_BGR2GRAY); //change to grayscale


    threshold(imageFinal, imageFinal, 20, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY); // change to grayscale


    imshow("Camera Window",imageFinal); //show video


    int key = cvWaitKey(10);     //Capture Keyboard stroke
    if (char(key) == 27)
    {
        break;      //If you hit ESC key loop will break.
    }

}
```

This code however returns a blank image regardless of whether the camera video have new images introduced to it.

Note that if I uncomment the `cvtColor`, convert both imagef(video frame) and imageb(static image) to grayscale before processing, i am able to retrieve the diff between the new image, however, there will be information loss due to similar intensity, yet if I lower down the threshold, the video have horizontal moving lines(in bright conditions, hence I can set it too low).

I wish to ask if absdiff only work on grayscale image? If it works on BGR images too, then where did I go wrong?

Comment: imageb never gets initialized ?

Comment: @berak, it does. The line  `capture>> imageb; `is placed before the while loop.

Comment: This is because I do not want the background to be "live" or changing. I wish for it to be constant.

Comment: @berak, solved it already. Apparently, i can't use `capture>>imageb;`. I have to use `capture>>imagef;` followed by `imagef.copyTo(imageb);`... which is weird. You have any idea why though? Both are different Mat, why do I need to add the extra line to make imageb?

Comment: no, the mats from the capture are *not* different, but all the same ( they point to static memory inside the capture ) - so you have to clone() after the capture ( this might also explain, why it worked with grayscale conversion, but not without - the conversion copies to a different mem location )

Comment: @berak, this might be a little slow, but please do repost this as an answer so i can reward you the rep. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The cv2.absdiff does indeed work on color images. I verified this. Your error is elsewhere.